# Bootstrap is placing my form-control below well when using col-sm

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following bootstrap html:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <form class="row loginContainer">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
            <div class="hidden-xs well" style="background: #0a0a0a;">
                <img style="max-width: 300px" src="/Images/Logon-Logo.png" />
                <div class="form-inline col-sm-6">
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.userName" placeholder="User Name" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Password" required />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

This causes my 2 textboxes to display below the well.  If I remove the col-sm-6, it displays correctly.

What is causing this and how do I fix it so I can have a col-sm-6 on my inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for? Wrap the form-inline in a new row and column.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<form class="row loginContainer">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6 col-lg-offset-4 col-lg-4">
        <div class="hidden-xs well" style="background: #0a0a0a;">
            <img style="max-width: 300px" src="/Images/Logon-Logo.png" />
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-inline">
                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-top: 20px;">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.userName" placeholder="User Name" required />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom: 20px;">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="model.password" placeholder="Password" required />
                    </div>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed it!  Thanks!